# How to get the index of a selected item in listbox and add to listbox two with button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am looking to get the index of the selected item in a list box to add the selected item to list box 2.

The listbox was created in HTML.

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="select-container">
  <select name="sometext" size="5">

<?
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[1]);
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
 var myRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+lastRow); 
 var data    = myRange.getValues();
?>

<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
 <option><?!= data[i] ?></option>
<? } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <div><button onclick='addMonitoredFolder()' id='button1'>Add</button></div>
</div>
```

So when I press button 'Add', I want the currently selected item in list box 1 to be added to listbox 2. It would be good that if the user selects multiple options in the list then it will add these or at least know how to handle this. I have function addMonitoredFolder in there because I was trying to figure it out by just can't get my head around it.

```
<div class="select-container">
  <select name="sometext" size="5">
    <option>option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Select elements have a *selectedIndex* property that is the index of the selected option, or -1 if none are selected. For multiple selected options, you need to loop over them to find those where `selected == true`.

Comment: var getindex = $("select[name='sometext'] option:selected").index()

Comment: @Eray—`document.querySelector('[name="sometext"]').selectedIndex` saves loading several thousand lines of some library (and a zillion function calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that can get multiple selections from a list, and transfer the choices to the second list:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>List Box One</div>

    <select id="slctOne" multiple>
      <option value="one">Value One</option>
      <option value="two">Value Two</option>
      <option value="three">Value Three</option>
      <option value="four">Value Four</option>
    </select>

    <div>List Box Two</div>

    <select id="slctTwo" multiple>
      <option value="one">Value One</option>
      <option value="two">Value Two</option>
      <option value="three">Value Three</option>
      <option value="four">Value Four</option>
    </select>

  <button onmouseup="getAndTransfer()">Get Choices</button>

  <p>Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.</p>

    <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript.html

```
<script>
window.getAndTransfer = function() {
  var allChoices = getMultiple();
  putChoicesIntoSelectTwo(allChoices);
};


window.getMultiple = function() {
  //console.log('getMultiple ran')
  var allOptionNodesSelected = document.getElementById('slctOne').querySelectorAll('option:checked');
  var howManySelected = allOptionNodesSelected.length;

  console.log('number of option nodes: ' + howManySelected);
  var optionElmt1 = allOptionNodesSelected[0];
  console.log('optionElmt1.selected: ' + optionElmt1.selected);

  var i=0,
      arryAllOptions = [];

  for(i=0;i<howManySelected;i+=1) {
    console.log('optionElmt1.selected: ' + allOptionNodesSelected[i].value);
    arryAllOptions.push(allOptionNodesSelected[i].value);
  };

  return arryAllOptions;
};

window.putChoicesIntoSelectTwo = function(theChoices) {
  //Get select list two element
  var selectListTwo = document.getElementById('slctTwo');

  var allOptions = selectListTwo.getElementsByTagName("option"); //Get all current options inside of this select tag
  var i = 0, thisOptionVal="";
  //console.log(allOptions.length);

  for (i=0;i<allOptions.length;i+=1) {
    thisOptionVal = allOptions[i].value;
    if (theChoices.indexOf(thisOptionVal) !== -1) {
      allOptions[i].selected = true;
    } else {
      allOptions[i].selected = false;
    };
  }; 
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.